# Has anyone had success installing Calculix 2.16 using the preCICE adapter?

Tags: installation, yaml-cpp, arpack

I am trying to install the 2.16 version of Calculix. When installing according to that described at (https://github.com/precice/calculix-adapter/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-CalculiX)to my system (Ubuntu 16), I get an error message

> (Makefile:66: home/user/CalculiX/CalculiX/ccx_2.16/src/Makefile.inc:
>   No such file or directory).

This is the code in Makefile at line 66:

```
# Include a list of all the source files
include $(CCX)/Makefile.inc   # CCX = $/home/user/CalculiX/calculix-adapter-master
SCCXMAIN = ccx_2.15.c
```

I have tried to copy Makefile.inc to both directories. I have tried to reinstall from start with SPOOLES, ARPACK and yaml-cpp. But I haven't gotten it right at the last step when I need to use "make" to build the libraries as described in the wiki *"Now in the calculix-adapter-master folder edit the Makefile to set path to libraries (SPOOLES, CCX, ARPACK, YAML) and build with make"*. Can anyone offer some advice for this issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the following src file from

wget http://www.dhondt.de/ccx_2.16.src.tar.bz2

then extract it using

```
tar xvjf ccx_2.16.src.tar.bz2
```

After this run `make` command for the precice calculix adapter